# ZF2 How to pass a variable to a form

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

What's the easiest way to pass a variable to a form in zend framework 2?

It seems you can only send a name value to the contructor, but i need to send a few options to the form to set/fill some selectors.

Thanks!

Comment: What about `$form->setAttribute`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you extend Form with your own class:

```
class MyForm extends \Zend\Form\Form
```

You can then pass in any variables you like via it's constructor and pass the form name to the parent Form class as such:

```
public function __construct($myVar, $myVar2)
{
    //do things with my vars
    $this->setVar($myVar);

    // send name to parent constructor
    parent::__construct('myFormName');
}
```

You might also want to consider using a `Factory` to inject your dependencies which can be configured for example in your `Module.php`:

```
public function getFormElementConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'MyForm' => function (ServiceManager $sm) {
                return new \MyNamespace\MyForm($sm->get('someDependancy'));
            },
        )
    );
}
```

This form is now available via the service locator from any service aware class:

```
$serviceLocator->get('FormElementManager')->get('MyForm');
```

With the dependencies injected via the factory.

Comment: Also you can pass options to the form by using the FormElementManager to retrieve your Forms. ie: $serviceLocator->get('FormElementManager')->get('App\My\Form', array('myOption' => 'foo'));