# Zend Framework 2: passing variables ("options") to form using formelementmanager

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I need to programmatically change the behaviour of a form based on some options. Let's say, for example, I'm displaying a form with some user's info.

I need to display a checkbox, "send mail", if and only if a user has not received an activation mail yet. Previously, with ZF1, i used to do something like

```
$form = new MyForm(array("displaySendMail" => true))
```

which, in turn, was received as an option, and which allow'd to do

```
class MyForm extends Zend_Form {

    protected $displaySendMail;

    [...]

    public function setDisplaySendMail($displaySendMail)
    {
        $this->displaySendMail = $displaySendMail;
    }


    public function init() {
        [....]
        if($this->displaySendMail)
        {
            $displaySendMail  new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox("sendmail");
            $displaySendMail
                   ->setRequired(true)
                   ->setLabel("Send Activation Mail");
        }
    }
```

How could this be accomplished using Zend Framework 2? All the stuff I found is about managing dependencies (classes), and nothing about this scenario, except this SO question: [ZF2 How to pass a variable to a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674282/zf2-how-to-pass-a-variable-to-a-form)
which, in the end, falls back on passing a dependency. Maybe what's on the last comment, by Jean Paul Rumeau could provide a solution, but I wasn't able to get it work.
Thx
A.

@AlexP, thanks for your support. I already use the FormElementManager, so it should be straightforward. If I understand correctly, I should  just retrieve these option in my SomeForm constructor, shouldn't I?

```
[in Module.php]

'Application\SomeForm' => function($sm)
           {
                $form = new SomeForm();
                $form->setServiceManager($sm);
                return $form;
            },
```

while in SomeForm.php

```
class SomeForm extends Form implements ServiceManagerAwareInterface
{
    protected $sm;

    public function __construct($name, $options) {
         [here i have options?]
         parent::__construct($name, $options);
    }
 }
```

I tryed this, but was not working, I'll give it a second try and double check everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the plugin managers (classes extending `Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager`) you are able to provide 'creation options' array as the second parameter.

```
$formElementManager = $serviceManager->get('FormElementManager');
$form = $formElementManager->get('SomeForm', array('foo' => 'bar'));
```

What is important is how you have registered the service with the manager. 'invokable' services will have the options array passed into the requested *service's* constructor, however 'factories' (which have to be a string of the factory class name) will get the options in it's constructor.

**Edit**

You have registered your service with an anonymous function which mean this will *not* work for you. Instead use a factory *class*.

```
// Module.php
public function getFormElementConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Application\SomeForm' => 'Application\SomeFormFactory',
        ),
    );
}
```

An then it's the *factory* that will get the options injected into it's constructor (which if you think about it makes sense).

```
namespace Application;

use Application\SomeForm;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;

class SomeFormFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    protected $options = array();

    public function __construct(array $options = array())
    {
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return new SomeForm('some_form', $this->options);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can inject directly into the service you are requesting (`SomeForm`) by registering it as an 'invokeable' service; obviously this will depend on what dependencies the service requires.

Comment: $this->options will stay the same ('foo' => 'bar') if I make second call like this:  $form2 = $formElementManager->get('SomeForm', array('foo' => 'bar2'));

Comment: @vlr The service will by default be 'shared'; meaning that once created, it continues to return the *same* instance on each call to `$formElementManager->get()`. You can disable this [by marking the service as non-shared](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html#sample-configuration) - Giving you a brand new service instance (using a new instance of `SomeFormFactory` factory each time).

Comment: I ended up using initilizers, and overriding getOptions() to retrieve and return params['options'].