# ZF2 instantiating classes from factories using MutableCreationOptionsTrait: creates the same instance of class no matter what

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

In ZF2, I have a factory like this

```
class SomeServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface, MutableCreationOptionsInterface
{
    use MutableCreationOptionsTrait;

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $serviceManager = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        $formElementManager = $serviceManager->get('FormElementManager');

        if ($this->creationOptions == 'value1') {
            return new SomeService(
                $formElementManager->get('Path\To\Form1'),
                $serviceManager->get('Path\To\Mapper1'),
                new Object1()
            );
        } elseif ($this->creationOptions == 'value2') {
            return new SomeService(
                $formElementManager->get('Path\To\Form2'),
                $serviceManager->get('Path\to\Mapper2'),
                new Object2()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller factory, I get several instances of `SomeService` based on the option value attached at the object creation, like

```
$service1 = $viewHelperManager->get('Path\To\SomeService', ['valueType' => 'value1']);
$service2 = $viewHelperManager->get('Path\To\SomeService', ['valueType' => 'value2']);
```

(these services are view helpers with their dependencies).

The problem is that `$service2` is the exact same object as `$service1` whereas it should have different dependencies. I tried to study the thing a bit, and it seems that the `$creationOptions` are not updated when assigning `$service2` despite the `valueType` is completely different.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally bumped into the answer in the comments (@AlexP if you can hear me, thanks buddy!) to the following question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28205176/4685379

By default, ZF2 shares the services. If you want to create a new service each time you call the factory, you need to specify the `shared` directive in the `module.confing.php` under the appropriate item like this:

```
'view_helpers' => [
    'factories' => [
        // some factories including the name of the one that 
        // you don't want to create new instances each time it's called
    ],
    'shared' => [
        'Alias\Of\That\Factory' => false,
    ],
],
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html#sample-configuration